# Angular-Reactive-Forms, getting error, Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am facing below error. Although I defined everything, I couldn't find anything in my code which I didn't define. I am pasting my code too please check why I am getting below error.

```
core.js:14597 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at BaseFormComponent.get [as idNumber] (http://localhost:4200/main.js:3636:44)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:145383:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)............
```

My html code:-

```
 <form class="flex flex-column flex-row-ns flex-wrap mt2" [formGroup]="identificationForm" >
     <mat-form-field class="w-50-ns pr2-ns">
    <mat-label>License Number</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="" formControlName="idNumber"/>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-error *ngIf="idNumber.invalid && idNumber.touched">
      {{ titleAlert }}
    </mat-error>

    </form>
```

My ts code:-

```
export class IdentificationComponent extends BaseFormComponent implements OnInit  {
    identificationForm: FormGroup;
    formBuilder: FormBuilder;
    idType: Array<any>;
    states: Array<any>;
    titleAlert: string = 'This field is required';

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initializeForm();

    }

    initializeForm() {
        this.identificationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            id: ['', [Validators.required]],
            state: ['', [Validators.required]],
            idNumber: ['', [Validators.required]],

        });
    }

    get idNumber() {
        return this.identificationForm.get('idNumber') as FormControl;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Try initializing the form group while declaring it. Like this: `identificationForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});`

Comment: I still get it .... this.identificationForm = new FormGroup({
   idNumber:  new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),........

Comment: Try this.identificationForm.controls['idNumber']

Comment: I declare it like that too. but still getting same error, I dont know what's wrong

Comment: The error is at Baseform it seems. Please post the code of it

Comment: I used same in other compoenents, other components are working using same.

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: Why don't you just do this: `<mat-error *ngIf="idNumber?.invalid && idNumber?.touched">`. The issue is that `idNumber` is trying to be invalidated before the `identificationForm` was initialized... Also, you can move the code for initalization in constructor but that still may not solve your issue...

Comment: please create a minimum reproduction on stackblitz

Comment: @miselking I did like that but still facing same error, although on UI side it works fine and  not blocking me but in console I am getting error

Comment: @SachinGupta my code is complex and if I start making stackblitz it gonna take forever.

Comment: Don't try to make a stackblitz of *your code* ... try instead to make a stackblitz to demonstrate **your issue**. Build a simple form with just enough logic to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible it's a timing issue? Are you binding to `idNumber` on the form somewhere? Maybe it's this:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="idNumber.invalid && idNumber.touched">
```

It may be that the binding is occurring before the form is initialized.

Though I just tried something similar in my code and it does not throw an exception in my example (though I'm not using material design). So it must be something specific to your scenario (hence the request for a stackblitz.)

You could try this:

```
get idNumber() {
    if (this.identificationForm) {
      return this.identificationForm.get('idNumber') as FormControl;
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked thanks :-). I don't know why it was not working and it worked with the code you posted

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

use *ngIf to avoid initial errors

```
<form *ngIf="identificationForm" [formGroup]="identificationForm" >
```

Use identificationForm.controls.idNumber to refered to "idNumber"

```
<mat-error *ngIf="identificationForm.controls.idNumber.invalid && 
                  identificationForm.controls.idNumber.touched">
```

NOTE:From Angular 7, you can refered as myForm.controls.nameOfField -it's not necesary use myForm.get('nameOfField') -